# Terminate AWS Lambda execution out of the handler function

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, aws-lambda

Is there a way to terminate the AWS Lambda function execution (.NET Core) in a method different than the one declared as a handler?

I tried to run "Environment.Exit(0)" when some condition is fulfilled but the execution results in the error as below:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "RequestId: fake-request-id Error: Runtime exited without providing a reason",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ExitError"
}
```

Comment: I've got one idea so far - to surround everything in the handler function with "try/catch" block that catches some custom exception (I could throw it instead of terminating the function).
I'm simply wondering if there's a simpler way.